# 2009 Naruto fanfic featuring some girl that previously had a power of 'XP counter and allocation'?

Tags: story-identification, isekai, fan-fiction, litrpg

Someone told me about a ~2009 Naruto fanfic from Fanfiction.net that featured some likely American girl.

The girl, who from birth or so, secretly used a power of 'XP counter and allocation' to be better at things, with one mentioned method of using "manga trivia" as an easy source of experience to shift into some other skill?

And using that experience literally caused her to lose her memories of it.

But, she's not the POV character. Instead, XP girl is the *cause* of the POV character, her sister, entering the Naruto world, by dragging her in.

Does anyone know this story?

Comment: Was it fantasy? Science fiction? Portal? Reincarnation? Virtual reality?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Not sure. I can't get my source right now, but I'll put a few guesses.

Comment: Was this a girl from America with a cat who has a crush on Kakashi?

Comment: Just to clarify, she has a cat and she has a crush on Kakashi, not that she has a cat that has a crush on Kakashi. :-D

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Not sure on that, but it seems EXP girl dragged her sister into the Naruto world?

Comment: I was initially thinking https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5265270/1/You-re-My-Favorite-Guilty-Pleasure, but it doesn't look like the sister actually gets pulled in.